# How to correctly expose interfaces from a dll in the presence of VC++ 2015 whole program optimization

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2015

recently we encountered in our legacy code that is currently ported from VS2010 to VS2015 an interesting effect. Unfortunately I couldn't create a small example that shows this effect, but I'll try to describe it as accurately as I can.

We have 2 dlls (I'll call them dll A and dll B). The project for dll A defines the interface IFoo & a derived interface IFxFoo

```
class __declspec(novtable) IFoo {
public:
    virtual int GetType() = 0;
    virtual ~IFoo() {}
};

class __declspec(novtable) IFxFoo : public IFoo {
public:
    virtual int GetSlot() = 0;
};
```

in dll B, both interfaces are used.

```
class CBImpl : public IFxFoo {
public:
    ...
    void processFoo(IFoo* f) {
        ...
        if (f->GetType() == IFXFOO) {
            IFxFoo* fx = static_cast<IFxFoo>(f); //downcast
            fill(fx);
        }
    }

    void fill(IFxFoo* fx) {
        m_slot = fx->GetSlot();
    }
private:
    int m_slot;
};
```

processFoo() will be called with different implementations of IFoo. Some from dll A and some from dll B.

What now happened was the following:
 - if we turned on whole program optimization when compiling dll B, the call to the virtual function GetSlot() in function fill() got de-virtualized by Visual C++. This caused our program to crash.
we can fix this behavior if we either

- turn of whole program optimization
- turn of optimization for fill
- or mark our interfaces with __declspec(dllimport) / __declspec(dllexport)

The questions that I have now are:

- is our assumption correct that the de-virtualization happened because the optimizer saw only one implementation of IFxFoo in dll B and assumed that this is the only one because IFxFoo was not marked to be from a different dll?
- what's the best way to create "interfaces" in header files? We used to do them like above but this seems to lead to some problems.
- do other compiler (gcc / clang) exhibit similar behavior?

Thank you for your help
Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LTO results in the compiler making drastic adjustments to any functions for which is it able to see the complete callgraph.

What you are seeing is expected and using `__declspec(dllexport)` or `extern` on the functions that need to be utilised from a separate module or explicitly declaring them as part of a DLL .def file is the expected way to resolve the problem as the compiler will no longer consider the functions to be internal-only.